# C - Unable to index inside a recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion

I am trying to index an array inside a recursive function, however the indexing is not working as expected, since I am unable to increment a counter inside the function. The problem can be simplified into the below code.

Here root is a pointer to a node structure which is a simple tree.

**Recursive function:**

```
void inorder(node *root, int in_count)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {       

        inorder(root->left, in_count);
        printf("key is %d and count is %d\n", root->KEY, root->node_count, in_count++);

        //index array arr[in_count];

        inorder(root->right, in_count);
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
int main()
{
    int in_count =0;
    printf("Inorder traversal of the given tree \n");
    inorder(root, in_count);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Inorder traversal of the given tree 
key is 1 and count is 0
key is 2 and count is 0
key is 2 and count is 1
key is 2 and count is 2
key is 3 and count is 0
key is 5 and count is 1
key is 7 and count is 2
key is 9 and count is 3
key is 12 and count is 0
```

I expected `in_count` to increment from 0 to 8, but this is not the case. Why is the count resetting? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to passe `count` as reference.

```
void inorder(node *root, int *pIn_count)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {       

        inorder(root->left, pIn_count);
        printf("count is %d \n", (*pIn_count)++);

        //index array arr[in_count];

        printf("%d ", root->KEY);
        inorder(root->right, pIn_count);
    }
}
```

And from `main`.

```
int main()
{
    int in_count =0;
    printf("Inorder traversal of the given tree \n");
    inorder(root, &in_count);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is one of the solutions. But could you give a brief explanation why is it working with reference passing and it doesn't with value passing?

Comment: @VladRusu because otherwise you only pass a copy to the called function which is never copied back into the instance that is visible in the calling function.

Comment: @VladRusu I'm not here to teach what is pass by reference and pass by value.
I have given the keyword("reference"). Let him do research.

Comment: I know :) I asked for it because in the question the OP asks why is the count resetting, so I thought a little explanation would help him. Also, using a global `in_count` is another valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a static variable to achieve the result. In the function declare count as static int count=0;, and increment it as you did before. Static variables are not stored in stack, they are stored in separate segment, so the value will persist.

The reason for count resetting is that in recursive calls, the changes made by the inner calls are not reflected on the caller. Callee uses a new copy of count whose changes are not reflected in the caller.